# Display long text inside Circular Button Completely

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

Am trying to create a Circular Button with Long Text inside it using Xamarin Forms. however on UWP platform if the text is longer than say 6 chars its Not visible completely.

**How can i make the text fit to Width and Height inside the button.**

Below is the Problem depicted .
in 3rd Button the Figure 100000 is cut at extreme right.

[image]

After increasing font size below is the Rendered UI.

[image]

The above has increased the font size however the text is cut off at corners.

FYI : Am using below Styles **only** on UWP to render button, is there any thing am doing wrong here? or how can i remove radius of textblock using this style?

```
 <Style x:Name="MyControl" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                 Background="White"
                                 CornerRadius="50"
                                Width="110"
                                 Padding="0"
                                 Margin="0"
                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                  IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"
                                  TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Could you share the code of circle button?

Comment: <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" Text="100000" WidthRequest="110" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="110" BackgroundColor="Red" BorderColor="Blue" BorderRadius="50" BorderWidth="10"/>

Comment: Does the style write in uwp project?

Comment: Yes, its a custom rendered view and Style is only for UWP

Comment: Ok, I am trying.

Comment: Great Thank you,Much appreciated.:)

Comment: I think  `MyControl` will not effect, I don't know why the button text has background color, could you share a simple sample for us?

Comment: I have shared both button and Style code with you already, `MyControl` is a hack around to disable click animation. `Background` color is to show text cutting off nothing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191065/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-tech-cruize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i make the text fit to Width and Height inside the button.

Xamarin button has [`FontSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.fontsize?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Button_FontSize) property. You could set suitable double value for displaying all text.

```
<Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60"
        BorderRadius="30" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        BorderColor="Green" 
        BorderWidth="5" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Text="100000"          
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        FontSize="10"/>
```

[image]

It looks correct in my side.

If you want avoid click animation, Please copy the following `FormsButton` style  that is removed `PointerOver` and `Pressed` storyboard to UWP Application Resource directly.

```
xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP"
<Style TargetType="forms:FormsButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />

    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="forms:FormsButton">
                <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"                            
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"                             
                    >

                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have updated my question,please have a look